# Using a randomly generated array as input values to print characters from a tuple

Tags: python, numpy

I am creating an `numpy.random.random_integers()` array based on user parameters of lowest integer, highest integer, and the number of the integers to be output in the array.

I then want to use every integer in a given array to print the corresponding value from a tuple.

Ex:

```
charTuple = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
randIntArray = np.random.random_integers(0, len(tuple), 12)
```

However, when I go to the next step, I get confused as to how to do such a process. Although this isn't the most elegant solution, I tried this, but I get index errors when I do and subsequently do not think this way would work.

```
for y in randIntArray:
    print(charTuple[randIntArray[y])
```

Does anyone have a better idea for doing such a process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print [charTuple[i] for i in randIntArray] # new list according to new indices
```

Special and commonly used way of indexing called `list comprehension`.

ps: I think this line should be:

```
randIntArray = np.random.random_integers(0, len(charTuple) - 1, 12)
```

Comment: Both of your examples worked well, but they only worked for cases in which there was a single int in the randIntArray. For all other cases I encountered a "TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index".

Is there another way I could transverse the randIntArray to print the corresponding tuple value?

Comment: @user3078611 Sorry, try the latter example as in the answer now. Previous one is wrong!

Comment: Thank you so much! You have been a great help!